# How to plot one variable against each of the three time points

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset containing one DV called Soma(Somatotype) and three IV called WT2(weight at age 2),WT9(weight at age9),WT18(weight at age18) and I am going to plot Soma against weight at each of the three time points. But since it is not exactly like a time series dataset and I am totally stuck with this.
I was thinking of use ggplot but I am not familiar with that and failed a lot.
The dataset:

```
structure(list(X = 67:136, Sex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
WT2 = c(13.6, 11.3, 17, 13.2, 13.3, 11.3, 11.6, 11.6, 12.4, 
17, 12.2, 15, 14.5, 10.2, 12.2, 12.8, 13.6, 10.9, 13.1, 13.4, 
11.8, 12.7, 11.8, 14.1, 10.9, 11.8, 13.6, 12.7, 12.3, 11.5, 
12.6, 14.1, 11.5, 12, 10.9, 12.7, 11.3, 11.8, 15.4, 10.9, 
13.2, 14.3, 11.1, 13.6, 12.9, 13.5, 16.3, 13.6, 10.2, 12.6, 
12.9, 13.3, 13.4, 12.7, 12.2, 15.4, 12.7, 13.2, 12.4, 10.9, 
13.4, 10.6, 11.8, 14.2, 12.7, 13.2, 11.8, 13.3, 13.2, 15.9
), HT2 = c(87.7, 90, 89.6, 90.3, 89.4, 85.5, 90.2, 82.2, 
85.6, 97.3, 87.1, 88.9, 87.6, 82.6, 87.1, 84, 83.6, 81.4, 
89.7, 88.4, 86.4, 83.8, 87.6, 94, 82, 86.4, 88.9, 86.7, 86.4, 
86.4, 83.8, 88.9, 85.9, 86.2, 85.1, 88.6, 83, 88.9, 89.7, 
81.3, 88.7, 88.4, 85.1, 91.4, 87.6, 86.1, 94, 85.9, 82.2, 
88.2, 87.5, 88.6, 86.9, 86.4, 80.9, 90, 94, 89.7, 86.4, 82.6, 
86.4, 81.8, 86.2, 86, 91.4, 88.9, 88.6, 86.4, 94, 89.2), 
WT9 = c(32.5, 27.8, 44.4, 40.5, 29.9, 22.8, 30, 24.3, 29.9, 
44.5, 31.8, 32.1, 39.2, 23.7, 26, 36.3, 29.9, 22.2, 34.4, 
35.5, 33, 25.7, 29.2, 31.7, 23.7, 35.3, 39, 30.8, 29.3, 28, 
33, 47.4, 27.6, 34.2, 28.1, 27.5, 23.9, 32.2, 29.4, 22, 28.8, 
38.8, 36, 31.3, 26.9, 33.3, 36.2, 29.5, 23.4, 33.8, 34.5, 
34.4, 38.2, 31.7, 26.6, 34.2, 27.7, 28.5, 30.5, 26.6, 39, 
25, 25.6, 34.2, 29.8, 27.9, 27, 41.4, 41.6, 42.4), HT9 = c(133.4, 
134.8, 141.5, 137.1, 136.1, 130.6, 136, 128, 132.4, 152.5, 
138.4, 135.2, 142.3, 129.1, 133.2, 136.3, 133.1, 123.2, 135.8, 
139.5, 139.4, 124.2, 135.6, 144.1, 123.8, 134.6, 137.2, 139.8, 
128.8, 134.2, 136.5, 140.8, 132.1, 137, 129, 139.4, 125.6, 
137.1, 133.6, 121.4, 133.6, 134.1, 139.4, 138.1, 133.2, 138.4, 
139.5, 132.8, 129.8, 144.8, 138.9, 140.3, 143.8, 133.6, 123.5, 
139.9, 136.1, 135.8, 131.9, 133.1, 130.9, 126.3, 135.9, 135, 
135.5, 136.5, 134, 138.2, 142, 140.8), LG9 = c(28.4, 26.9, 
31.9, 31.8, 27.7, 23.4, 27.2, 25.1, 27.5, 32.7, 28.3, 26.9, 
31.6, 25.9, 26.7, 28.4, 26.2, 24.9, 32.3, 30, 26.9, 26.2, 
26.3, 27.2, 25.5, 30.4, 32.4, 26, 28.3, 25, 29, 32.3, 26.3, 
27.3, 27.4, 25.7, 24.5, 28.2, 26.6, 24.4, 26.5, 31.1, 28.2, 
27.6, 26.3, 29.4, 28, 27.6, 22.6, 28.3, 30.5, 31.2, 29.8, 
27.5, 27.2, 29.1, 26.7, 25.5, 28.6, 25.4, 29.3, 25, 23.7, 
27.6, 27, 26.5, 26.5, 32.5, 31, 32.6), ST9 = c(74L, 65L, 
104L, 79L, 83L, 60L, 67L, 44L, 76L, 81L, 59L, 67L, 72L, 40L, 
40L, 54L, 67L, 58L, 57L, 61L, 64L, 48L, 61L, 74L, 50L, 58L, 
80L, 57L, 44L, 46L, 57L, 69L, 51L, 44L, 48L, 68L, 22L, 59L, 
58L, 44L, 58L, 57L, 64L, 64L, 58L, 73L, 52L, 52L, 60L, 107L, 
62L, 88L, 78L, 52L, 40L, 71L, 30L, 76L, 59L, 75L, 38L, 50L, 
45L, 62L, 57L, 66L, 54L, 44L, 56L, 74L), WT18 = c(56.9, 49.9, 
55.3, 65.9, 62.3, 47.4, 57.3, 50, 58.8, 80.2, 59.9, 56.3, 
67.9, 52.9, 58.5, 73.2, 54.7, 44.1, 70.5, 60.6, 73.2, 57.2, 
56.4, 56.6, 46.3, 63.3, 65.4, 60.1, 55, 55.7, 71.2, 65.5, 
57.2, 58.2, 56, 64.5, 53, 52.4, 56.8, 49.2, 55.6, 77.8, 69.6, 
56.2, 52.5, 64.9, 59.3, 54.2, 49.8, 62.6, 66.6, 65.3, 65.9, 
59, 47.4, 60.4, 56.3, 61.7, 52.4, 52.1, 58.4, 52.8, 60.4, 
61, 67.4, 54.3, 56.3, 97.7, 68.1, 63.1), HT18 = c(158.9, 
166, 162.2, 167.8, 170.9, 164.9, 168.1, 164, 163.3, 183.2, 
167, 163.8, 174, 163, 167.1, 168.1, 163, 154.6, 170.3, 170.6, 
175.1, 156.5, 160.3, 170.8, 156.5, 165.2, 169.8, 171.2, 160.4, 
163.8, 169.6, 172.7, 162.4, 166.8, 157.1, 181.1, 158.4, 165.6, 
166.7, 156.5, 168.1, 165.3, 163.7, 173.7, 163.9, 169.2, 170.1, 
166, 164.2, 176, 170.9, 169.2, 172, 163, 154.5, 172.5, 175.6, 
167.2, 164, 162.1, 161.6, 153.6, 177.5, 169.8, 173.5, 166.8, 
166.2, 162.8, 168.6, 169.2), LG18 = c(34.6, 33.8, 35.1, 39.3, 
36.3, 31.8, 35, 31.2, 36.2, 42.9, 36.5, 32.6, 37.5, 37.7, 
34.5, 37.2, 33.2, 32.4, 40.1, 38.2, 35.1, 35.6, 34.6, 32.6, 
32.9, 38.5, 38.6, 33, 36.3, 33.2, 38.8, 36.2, 36.5, 34.3, 
37.8, 34.2, 32.4, 33.8, 32.7, 33.5, 34.1, 39.8, 38.6, 34.2, 
34.6, 36.7, 32.8, 34.9, 30.3, 35.8, 38.8, 39, 35.7, 32.7, 
32.2, 35.7, 34, 35.5, 34.8, 34.1, 33, 33.4, 34.3, 34.5, 34.5, 
33.6, 36.2, 42.5, 38.4, 37.9), ST18 = c(143L, 117L, 143L, 
148L, 152L, 126L, 134L, 77L, 118L, 135L, 118L, 96L, 131L, 
108L, 99L, 105L, 122L, 146L, 126L, 124L, 100L, 118L, 123L, 
131L, 101L, 121L, 182L, 116L, 127L, 130L, 107L, 134L, 120L, 
130L, 101L, 149L, 112L, 136L, 118L, 110L, 104L, 138L, 108L, 
134L, 108L, 141L, 122L, 125L, 128L, 168L, 126L, 142L, 132L, 
116L, 112L, 137L, 114L, 122L, 121L, 148L, 107L, 140L, 125L, 
124L, 123L, 89L, 135L, 125L, 142L, 142L), Soma = c(5, 4, 
5.5, 5.5, 4.5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5.5, 5, 5, 5.5, 4, 5, 6.5, 4.5, 
3.5, 5.5, 4.5, 6, 5, 4.5, 4, 4, 5, 4.5, 4.5, 5, 5, 6, 4.5, 
5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 6.5, 5.5, 3.5, 4, 5, 4.5, 
4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5.5, 5.5, 4, 4, 3, 4.5, 5, 4, 6.5, 5, 3.5, 
5.5, 5, 4, 4.5, 7, 5.5, 5.5)), .Names = c("X", "Sex", "WT2", 
"HT2", "WT9", "HT9", "LG9", "ST9", "WT18", "HT18", "LG18", "ST18", 
"Soma"), row.names = 67:136, class = "data.frame")
```

my command:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
newdata.girls %>% 
# put WT2, WT9, WT18 in the weight column
# and the weights in the value column
gather(weight, value, -Soma) %>% 
# make WT2, WT9, WT18 factors and order them so as
# they plot in the correct order
mutate(weight = factor(weight, levels = c("WT2", "WT9", "WT18"))) %>%
# plot Soma versus value by time
ggplot(aes(Soma, value)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ weight)
```

It gives out a column of NA.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9rhJ.png)

Comment: Please provide some example data.

Comment: You'll probably want to transform your data from wide to long (using `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::gather`) before using `ggplot2`

Comment: getting close :) can you provide the data as plain text, not as an image

Comment: @neilfws I was trying to provide the data as plain text but the format is a little weird...

Comment: Don't worry about format, someone can fix that. Just needs to be text so people can copy/paste.

Comment: In your R console, type `dput(x)` (where `x` is your data); if the data is big, use `dput(head(x))` instead. Copy the output, edit your question, and paste, highlight it again (in the edit box), type `Ctrl-k` to indent it, then save your edits.

Comment: @neilfws I have fixed myself!Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans Thank you.Do you mean put all the four variable into dput(x) like dput(Soma,WT2,WT9,WT18)? The dataset is not big at all.

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% gather(Age, Weight, -Soma) %>% mutate(Age = parse_number(Age)) %>% ggplot(aes(Weight, Soma)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~Age)` or some variation of that; it's not clear what you want where.

Comment: SuxiZheng, I just put in a suggested edit with *one method* (among several) that makes it very easy for others to use your data. (This is a somewhat-ugly technique, others exist that are easier to see.)

Comment: @r2evans Thank you so much!

Comment: @alistaire What I want is to plot soma based on the three different weight groups to see how the relationship between weight and somatotype changes over time.

Comment: That's not a useful description. What variable is on the x axis, the y, and which is facetted (or otherwise presented)? Or in what way is the plot produced by the code I posted above not what you're looking for?

Comment: @alistaire The three weight variables are on the x axis, and I think the plot is like how soma changes based on the three time points. I tried the code but it doesn't work.

Comment: The data isn't tidy, but you have three variables: age, weight, and somatotype. They need to be mapped to locations, probably the x and y axes and different subplots ("facets", in ggplot parlance). You have still not clarified which goes where. And how did the code fail? What did it say?

Comment: Tip: it is not helpful to completely change the example data after working answers have been provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear how you would like the output to look, or if `Soma` is continuous or categorical. But taking your sentence "Soma against weight at each of the three time points" as a start point, an initial attempt could look like this. Assume your data frame is named `df1`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>% 
  # put WT2, WT9, WT18 in the weight column
  # and the weights in the value column
  gather(weight, value, -Soma) %>% 
  # make WT2, WT9, WT18 factors and order them so as
  # they plot in the correct order
  mutate(weight = factor(weight, levels = c("WT2", "WT9", "WT18"))) %>%
  # plot Soma versus value by time
  ggplot(aes(Soma, value)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ weight) + theme_light()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: all of these four variables are continuous variables, this answer is quite helpful!!Thanks!

Comment: but this looks a little weird when I run it.

Comment: could you please see the result I just added into my question.?

Comment: I see that your example dataset is now completely different to that in the original question. So it is no surprise that the code now fails. The easiest fix is to select only those variables that you want in the plot. So before the gather: `%>% select(Soma, WT2, WT9, WT18) %>%`.

Comment: Suxi Zheng, if this answers your question, I suggest you "accept" the answer. It's a courtesy to neilfws for taking the time to address your original and modified questions.